# Homomorphisms Groups Kernel

Tags: group-theory, functions, group-homomorphism

Given G: group  of units in Z mod 14 under multiplication.  A function sends the integers under addition to G.

$f(n)$ = $[3]^n$

I am just checking whether I am correct in stating that the kernel is simply the order which would be 6 and this would represented as  <6>.

Comment: Do you mean $<6>$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(6n)=[3]^{6n}=[729]^n=[1]^n=[1]$

Or if you want to be more pedantic, you can show that if $x\in \ker(f)$ then $x=6k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose not, then write $x$ as $6k+j$ where $j\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Calculation should be straightforward.

Comment: So can I conclude that the quotient group of the integers and <6> is isomorphic to G by the FHT?

Comment: @danny Yes, you are correct.